# Suppressing Window Security Warning Message

Tags: vba, security, https, warnings, message

I am looking for way to check if files exist in a SharePoint location.  I am using a function that performs this action but a message box titled: Windows Security Warning, with the message "This pages is accessing information that is not under its control.  This poses a security risk. Do you want to continue?"

Here is the function I am using:

```
Public Function SP_File_Exists (URLString as String) as Boolean
    Dim oHttPRequst as Object
    
    if Len(Trim(URLString)) =0 Then 
    SP_File_Exists = False
    Exit Function

    Set oHttpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
With oHttpRequest
   .Open "GET", URLString, False
   .Send
End With

If oHttpRequest.Status = 200 Or Left(oHttpRequest.Status, 1) = 3 Then  ' '300 to accommodate redirects
    SPFile_Exists = True
Else
    SPFile_Exists = False
End If
   
End Function
```

Is there a way to suppress the message?  I have tried using DisplayAlerts property and it doesn't work.  I am hopeful that someone has conquered this problem.

Comment: If you could suppress this message, so could a virus. Do not attempt to work around security protections, it could compromise your users in the name of convenience.

Comment: You can try using a different library like: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/about-winhttp which is called with `CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")`

Comment: As **@HackSlash** mention it, switching from use `XMLHTTP60` to`WinHTTP` resolved the issue. Thank you.